# C AVL tree search using recursion bug

Tags: c

I am having trouble searching for the largest size generic vector in a node, and returning the address of that node. I thought my logic was sound, but it keeps failing without any indication why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
struct vector
{        
    int size;
    int capacity;
    Item* data;
};
typedef struct vector GenericVector;    
typedef struct Node Tree;

struct Node
{    
    Tree* left;
    Tree* right;
    GenericVector* data;
    int height;
};

void* find_largest_bin(void* root)
{    
    Tree* pRoot = (Tree*)root;
    if (pRoot == NULL)
        return NULL;
    Tree* left = pRoot->left;
    Tree* right = pRoot->right;

    left= find_largest_bin(pRoot->left);
    right = find_largest_bin(pRoot->right);

    //if there is only one leg
    if (right == NULL && left->data->size > pRoot->data->size)
        return left;
    else if (right == NULL && left->data->size < pRoot->data->size)
        return pRoot;
    else if (left == NULL && right->data->size > pRoot->data->size)
        return right;
    else if (left == NULL && right->data->size < pRoot->data->size)
        return pRoot;
    //if there are two legs
    else if (left->data->size > pRoot->data->size && left->data->size > right->data->size)
        return left;
    else if (right->data->size > pRoot->data->size && right->data->size > left->data->size)
        return right;
    else
        return pRoot;
}
```

Comment: This seems like it may be a homework problem. Homework questions are welcome, and when asking one, it is appropriate to be clear that it is a homework question. If not, carry on.

Comment: I was not aware, my apologies (I am not too familiar with the etiquette concerning posting on this site), I will keep that in mind for future posts. it is one of many functions in a large lab project for school. I did not want to include the rest because I know they work, and it would have added unnecessary confusion.

Comment: "failing" is not a very specific description of what is going wrong. Can you provide a more precise description? Is it producing an incorrect answer? or is it crashing? Have you run it in "gdb" or some other debugger? Also, what is the contents of the tree?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've provided a code fragment that can't compile (`Item` isn't a defined type).  You need to learn how to use a debugger, or how to add useful diagnostic printing to your code, or both.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you all for your help.

@DavidJeske It would compile, then while running it would crash with a pop up that said "Your program crashed, would you like to send an error report?"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am still in my Freshman year, but learning to use a debugger and diagnostic tools is very high on my priorities list. I was hoping one of the professors would introduce them but I have yet to see any indication of that happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this first conditional occurs:

```
if (right == NULL && left->data->size > pRoot->data->size)
        return left;
```

It is possible that left is also null. This means left->data is dereferencing a null pointer, and likely to cause a crash. This is happening because you are checking that right is NULL and then assuming left is not. Don't assume. Instead check left is not null, then test left, check right is not null then test right.

Also, in general it is a bad habit to create functions with many return statements. Usually (but not always!) it is better to allow conditionals to fall through to a final return statement. This helps simplify logic and readability. By putting a return statement in every clause, you are forcing yourself to write a conditional for every possible permutation of (left,right) x (null,greater,less), instead of constructing a result by handling each case individually.

For example, try this version, which has many fewer operations, and is arguably more readable. Notice that we test left is not null, then look for a larger left; we check right is not null, then look for a larger right. Whichever is remaining in our `largest_so_far` variable is the largest, so we return it. Because we handle each node individually (this,left,right), and we accumulate `largest_so_far` in a variable, we only have to handle each case once.

```
Node* find_largest_bin(Node* curNode)
{    
    if (curNode == NULL) { return NULL; }

    Node* largest_so_far = curNode;

    // look for a larger node on the lefthand side
    Node* left_largest = find_largest_bin(curNode->left);      
    if (left_largest != NULL && 
          left_largest->data->size > largest_so_far->data->size) {
        largest_so_far = left_largest; 
    }

    // look for a larger node on the righthand side
    Node* right_largest = find_largest_bin(curNode->right);  
    if (right_largest != NULL && 
          right_largest->data->size > largest_so_far->data->size) {
         largest_so_far = right_largest;
    }

    return largest_so_far;
}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, I have been banging my head against the wall for about 20 hours now trying to figure out this question. Thank you!

Comment: To solve these kinds of problems yourself, you should learn to use a debugger. If you are on UNIX, you can run your program under the command-line `gdb` debugger. If you are working on windows or mac, you probably have an IDE and need to run your program in debugging mode. This will show the source-line where the problem occurs, and let you inspect the contents of variables at that point.